# It isn't letting me store a variable to an array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

hey guys so I have this program which its basic function is to create a set and ask the user to add an input. The program will then check the input so that if that input is already in the  program it asks the user to enter a single input.

This is the struct I have been working with:

```
struct memory
{
    int num;
    char element[MAXNUMB];
};
typedef struct memory *Item;
```

This is the Create function:

```
Item Create()
{
   Item set;
   set=(Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
   set->num=0;
   return set;
}
```

and this is the Add function:

```
void Add(Item S,int x)//add an element to set S
{
    Item set;
    int i,flags;
    flags=0;
    if(S==NULL)//gives error if set doesn't exist
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation failed. Goodbye!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Please enter an input: ");//takes input from user
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)//checking for similar inputs
    {
        if(set->element[i]!=x)
        {
            flags=1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(flags!=1)
                flags=0;
        }
    }
    while(flags==0)
    {
        printf("Error! Integer already exists! Please enter a different input: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(set->element[i]!=x)
            {
                flags=1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(flags!=1)
                    flags=0;
            }
        }
    }
    set->element[set->num]=x;//it is crashing on this line
    printf("x");
    n++;
    set=realloc(set,n*sizeof(Item));
    set->num++;
}
```

My program is crashing on this line

```
set->element[set->num]=x;
```

I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice about how to tackle this problem. Thanks

Comment: In Create(), use sizeof(struct memory). You're using sizeof(Item), item is a pointer, so You allocate space just for one pointer, not for the structure.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I fixed that. Now my problem is that it crashes on set->element[set->num].

Comment: I've managed to get your program to compile but there seems to be a problem with the validation step with the program as shown, it repeatedly claims "Integer already exists" probably because flags is set if the number input is not found.

Comment: It used to show that error to me but then I fixed it only to realize that it crashes shortly afterwards due to the problem that I'm trying to solve now.

Comment: Isn't Item set an initialization?

Comment: `char element[MAXNUMB];` -> `int element[MAXNUMB];`

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
set=(Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
```

Should read

```
set=malloc(sizeof(struct memory));
```

As you want to allocate more memory than just a pointer

Comment: You think that's what causing my program to crash? I'll try it now.

Comment: Then Your set->num probably exceeded MAXNUMB. If this is the case, You should check where and why does this happen.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the previous answer (you also need to change your `realloc` in the same way), It looks like in your `Add` function,

a) `set` is not initialized

b) `n` doesn't seem to be declared

c) `x` is a parameter passed by value and you are overwriting the value in your call to `scanf`

Comment: n is declared outside as 1 so that it doesn't reset its value each time the add function is called. Also, x isn't just a temporary variable so that it is used to store in the array?

Comment: I realized just now, I did Item set at the top of my Add function.

Answer (score 0):

Your allocation is wrong: You `typedef` Item to be a pointer, then you allocate memory for that pointer, and incorrectly use it for the data itself. Try replacing

```
Item set;
set=(Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
```

by

```
Item set = malloc(sizeof(*set));
```

The use of the dereferenced variable itself as an argument to the `sizeof()` operator ensures that the malloc'ed memory is indeed what you try to allocate.

Also note that it is not necessary in C to cast the return value `malloc()` since a `void*` can implicitely be converted to any pointer. However, if you want your code to be valid C++ as well, you need to retain the cast.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the crash problem. I had to define set as below:

```
Item set=Create();
```

Thanks for your help guys.